# Is it possible to convert C++/MEX(Matlab) code to standalone C++?

Tags: c++, matlab

I am looking for C++/standalone code from MEX function which has been written in [here](http://www.shawnlankton.com/2009/04/sfm-and-active-contours/). Is it possible to make C++ standalone easily from C++/MEX files? if it is possible, any tips to do it easier and do it faster is appreciated.

For example how to convert Mexfunction arguments to C++ types

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

  //declare variables
  mxArray *phi_out, *C_out, *label_out, *mxPhi, *C_in;
const mxArray *mxImg;

  const mwSize *mdims;
  double *img, *phi, *B, *mask, *C, *label;
  double *F;
  double usum, vsum, dthresh, lambda, rad;
  int    iter,countdown,display;
  long    dims[5];
  long    dimx, dimy, dimz, numdims;
  LL *Lz, *Ln1, *Ln2, *Lp1, *Lp2;
  LL *Sz, *Sn1, *Sn2, *Sp1, *Sp2;
  LL *Lin2out, *Lout2in;
// and .....
```

i.e. What is mxArray, LL types and how to define it in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy, but can't be done in an automated manner because many MATLAB specific functions require a running copy of MATLAB. If you really, really can't change the source, you might be able to write a shim layer that does from MATLAB function calls to their C equivalent but that would be bad idea.

`mxArray` can be mapped to a `void*`, in MEX its paradigmatic to cast everything.

```
The entry in `matrix.h` looks like:
/*
 * Forward declaration for mxArray
 */
typedef struct mxArray_tag mxArray;

/*
 * Type representing the signature for MEX functions.
 */
typedef void (*mxFunctionPtr) (int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[]);
```

Comment: what do you mean running copy of matlab?  should I have copy of Matlab in the computer that I run the code always? it cant be standalone then?

Comment: Mex files will call functions that should only be called from a running copy of MATLAB. For example, functions that register memory. On the other hand most mex files contain intelligible C/C++ code that can be manually modified and you can convert it to standard library calls without much effort.